# About countability of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let's denote reals as $b_N...b_3b_2b_1.a_1a_2a_3...$.

Can there be an $x \in \Bbb R : \forall n \in \Bbb N$ $\exists n_0 \in \Bbb N: (n_0>n) \land (a_{n_0}=8),$ but for all previous decimal numbers $a_i=9$?

If there exists such $x$ then isn't it the "previous" number of the number we are testing but all decimals be $9$?

I know that $\Bbb R$ is not countable, but isn't the above statement right?

Comment: If 5 is one such $n_0$, then there is no $n_0$ for $n=5$.

Comment: So this number has an infinite number of occurrences of the digit 8 in its decimal expansion, and all other digits are 9s? $1 - \sum_{n= 1}^\infty 10^{-n^2}$ has this property.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Why would it have an infinite number of occurrences of $8$? And, I think in your example, not all previous decimal numbers are $9$

Comment: By the definition of $x$, for every natural number $n$, there is a natural number $n_0 > n$ such that the $n_0$th decimal place of $x$ is 8. That requires an infinite number of occurrences of 8, because there is no natural number greater than all the others.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Ok, I get it now. Many thanks!

Comment: @eyeballfrog or ZeroPancakes, one of you might want to answer the question so it no longer appears unanswered on the site.

Comment: @MarkS. Can do.

Answer (score 1):

> Can there be an $x \in \Bbb R : \forall n \in \Bbb N\;\exists n_0 \in \Bbb N: (n_0>n) \land (a_{n_0}=8)$ , but for all previous decimal numbers $a_i=9$?

No. Suppose $x$ exists. Then there exists $n_0 > 0$ such that $a_{n_0} = 8$ and for all $n < n_0$, $a_n = 9$. However, we also know that there exists another number $n_0' > n_0$ such that $a_{n_0'}= 8$ and for all $n < n_0'$, $a_n = 9$. Since $n_0 < n_0'$, we have $a_{n_0} = 9$. Thus, $8 = 9$, and this contradiction demonstrates no such number can exist.

The key insight here is that the definition of $x$ requires that the $8$ to appear in a later position than all the $9$s. But that means the index of its position would be a natural number that is greater than all the others. Since there's no biggest natural number, we can conclude such a decimal expansion can't exist.